# Add class to an image field for a specific content type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Currently I'm using the code as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044263/1165159). Which is the following:

```
function simalr_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'request-background') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'pixastic';
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'pixastic-blurfast(amount=1)';
    }
}
```

This works fine except for the fact that I get the following error message on a page which doesn't have an Image with the 'request-background' style:

> Notice: Undefined index: style_name in simalr_preprocess_image() (line 46 of /var/www/vhosts/simalr.com/httpdocs/sites/all/themes/simalr/template.php).

I only want this piece of code used on a specific content type (namely 'request'). In which way do I have to adjust the code in my template.php file in order to just use it on a page which is only of a certain content type?

Answer (score 0):

You can still work with your code but use `isset` function. This will remove the warning.

If you want to do it just for a specific content type use `menu_get_object` function in drupal. This function will return the node for you if it's a node page.

Example:

```
$node = menu_get_object();

if ($node->type == 'story') {
  // TODO
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this and still I'm getting errors. Could you maybe rework my code to give me a better example?